# moment.js moment function returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
let date = moment('08.01.2021').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

date is returned `2021-01-07 03:00:00` but i want to see date `2021-01-08 00:00:00`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe set the timezone?

Comment: yeah, agree, timezone problem, I tested your code and it said the expected return value. If you want to add the hours, you need to add them to your format string as well

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need Moment, you can use ISO at 15:00

```js
const d = new Date("08.01.2021 15:00:00")

console.log(d.toISOString().split("T")[0])
```